# Potential difference and voltage

Tags: potential, voltage

Is potential difference between two points the voltage?

**(or)**

Is voltage the potential difference between two points?

**(or)**

Are they both the same?

Comment: Potential difference has units of Volts. And since people are too lazy to say 'potential difference', they shorten it to 'voltage'.

Comment: So what's the final conclusion

Comment: Strictly speaking [general circuits might not have a "potential"](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75349/if-electromagnetic-induction-generates-a-potential-difference-in-a-loop-where-a) in the mathematical sense in which the gradient of the potential gives a curl-free electric field (because the electric field may not be curl-free). In that case using "EMF" or "voltage" could be taken to be more precise. Or you can just take them to mean the same thing, and have the bit about changing magnetic flux as an unstated understanding.