# Why is the phase space of a simple pendulum defined on a cylinder and not $\mathbb{T}^{2}$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, topology, phase-space, complex-systems

Let's take the pendulum equation $\ddot{x} = -\sin x$. Here $x \in \mathbb{T}^{1}$. Now rewrite it as a coupled first order system $$\dot{y} = -\sin x, \quad \dot{x}=y.$$

Intuitively we know that $y$ corresponds to velocity, the norm of which (i.e. speed) can be as large or small as we want, thus $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence the phase space of the pendulum is the cylinder $\mathbb{T}^{1} \times \mathbb{R}$.

However $x(t) = x(t+t_{0})$ for some period $t_{0}$ and by the definition $ y =\dot{x}$ we also expect $y(t)=y(t+t_{0})$, i.e. we can say $y \in \mathbb{T}^{1}$.

Is this a contradiction? Why do we define $y$ to be in $\mathbb{R}$ and not in $\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: That's...not how you write the harmonic oscillator. The equation for the harmonic oscillator is $m\ddot{x} = -kx$, not $\ddot{x} = -\sin(x)$! Also, $y=\dot{x}$ holds only on trajectories that are solutions to the equations of the (correct) equations of motion, not throughout the phase space ($\dot{x}$ doesn't even make sense without a trajectory). I'm not sure which of those exactly your problem is.

Comment: That's why I said "Simple pendulum", not a harmonic oscillator! Anyway, the context of my question focuses on the mathematical aspect, rather than the physics (I just used the term pendulum because it's a common example of a cylinder phase space for a dynamical system) @ACuriousMind

Comment: To me, the "simple" in "simple pendulum" means that we consider the approximation of small angles where it becomes *simple*. Anyway, it seems your underlying question is "Why does having a circle for the values of a generalized coordinate not force a circle for the values of its conjugate momentum?", right?

Comment: Essentially, yes. But I have a much more general question concerning an arbitrary dynamical system, without any relevance to physics:  when we reduce the order of an ode by introducing a new variable, how do we determine in what space that new variable is? So suppose we had that ode I wrote above...without any reference to a pendulum. How would we decide if $y \in \mathbb{R}$, based on knowledge that $x \in \mathbb{T}$?... @ACuriousMind

Answer (score 5):

$x\in \mathbb{T}^1$ denotes the structure of the phase space itself, not the fact that the motion as a function of time is periodic. Any arbitrary motion of the pendulum can be represented in the phase space, not just the ones periodic (in time).  We have $x\in \mathbb{T}^1$ because you can rotate the pendulum around the hinge for a full cycle and you end up with the same state. You cannot say the same for $y$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your comment gives me some valuable insights here. What about the general case, without any reference to physics. Suppose you have a 2nd order ode. You make a change of variables $y= \dot{x}$ to reduce the system to a first order coupled ode system. Suppose $x$ is in some space: say $x \in \mathbb{T}$. What can you say about $y$? Will it be in $\mathbb{T}$ or $\mathbb{R}$? @pathintegral

Comment: If you take out the physics I don't think you can say anything about $y$. In quantum mechanics, a situation when $y\in \mathbb{T}^1$ is when continuous translation is degraded to discrete ones, i.e., when your "universe" is a crystal lattice. But in QM, a state cannot be represented by a point in phase space because of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. The size of the "pixel" in phase space is $\hbar$.

Answer (score 4):

1. If the [Lagrangian formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) has [configuration space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space) $M$, and the [Legendre transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) is non-singular, then the corresponding phase space in the [Hamiltonian formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) is the [cotangent bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_bundle) $T^{\ast}M$. (For the [pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_%28mathematics%29), the configuration space $M\cong S^1$ is a circle.)
2. For models with a 2-torus $S^1\times S^1$ as phase space, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126676/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 0):

Lagrangian mechanics is defined on a tangent bundle, the tangent bundle of the configuration space. For the pendulum the configuration space is $S^1$ the circle. Its tangent bundle is trivial, so it is $S^1 \times \mathbb R$.

You can pass to the Hamiltonian description, which lives on the cotangent bundle -- it too is trivial, so it is also $S^1 \times \mathbb R$. That is the space of *initial conditions*. The actual motion will be periodic in both variables, but that's something else.

(There is something called invariant tori, where the almost periodic motion traces out a torus in phase space. I'm not sure that applies to the pendulum.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider all possible motions of the pendulum, $x=x_I(t)\:, \dot{x}=\dot{x}_I(t)$ where $I=\{x_0, \dot{x}_0\}$ denotes the initial conditions of that solution of Hamilton equations. Varying $I$ you have all possible solutions.

Well, there is an evident asymmetry between the two Hamiltonian variables. $x$ can always be taken in a circle, as $-\pi \leq x \leq +\pi$ is enough to describe all motions of the pendulum independently from $I$.
A larger interval would be redundant to describe the positions of the pendulum.
 Conversely, there is no sufficiently large interval $[-\dot{X}, \dot{X}]$ which may include **all** values of **all** functions $\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto \dot{x}_I(t)$ for **every** initial condition $I$. This fact holds even if every such curve $\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto \dot{x}_I(t)$ is periodic.