# Physical meaning of theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, topology, phase-space

[image]

This is the image of theorem from V.I Arnold's Mathematical method of mechanics. I understood the example given in text. But I want to know what is physical meaning of example? Can anybody help?

Comment: See this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126676/

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the example shows that a [symplectic vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_field) $X$ is *not* necessarily a globally defined [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field). If $X$ is the time-evolution vector field, it means physically that there is not a globally defined notion of energy.