# Hamiltonian description of a system

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I know that phase space is the Hamiltonian description of a system, where we deal with position and momentum in equal footing. My question is in this phase space are those position and momentum are basis for that system?

As far as I know they are independent, in Hamiltonian dynamics, but how can I say that they are orthogonal basis functions? As alwayas we draw position and momentum line perpendicularly!

Comment: What do you mean by basis for the system? What quantities are you writing out as linear superpositions of the generalized positions and momenta?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450479/2451

Answer (score 2):

If the question is if the Hamiltonian phase space has the structure of a vector space equipped with a scalar product, the answer is negative, in general.

It is true that  generalized coordinates and momenta of a system with $n$  spatial degrees of freedom are **locally** represented by $2 n$ real numbers and $\mathbb R^{2 n}$ can be seen as a $2 n$ dimensional vector space. But the impossibility, in general, of a global mapping of the phase space on $\mathbb R^{2 n}$  prevents the possibility of identifying coordinates and momenta as a vector.

As a simple example, which shows why  there is such limitation, is the phase space of a rigid body in 3D. Coordinates represent three independent angles. However the set of rotation is not a vector space because in general $3D$ finite rotations around different axes do not commute.

It turns  out that the most natural structure of the Hamiltonian phase space is that of a [symplectic differentiable manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold). Which implies that, besides the failure of a general identification with a vector space, even at local level, the most important  property of Hamiltonian coordinates is not related to the concept of *angle* and scalar product, but to the concept of local volume.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that its even easier to see that the global phase space is not a vector space simply because the base topological manifold in this case is not homeomorphic to $R^n$. Its fairly easy to see that if one of the coordinates is an angle it must "wrap around" in a way that $R^n$ does not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're making a soup of concepts which have nothing to do
with one another. My suspicion derives e.g. from your use of words
like "orthogonal" and "basis", which I would see better in context
about QM.

As to drawing "position and momentum line perpendicularly" you're
attributing weight to an innocent practice: if I have a 2D space, it's
usual to draw a map of its coordinates in a Cartesian plane. But you
shouldn't give the drawing more properties than it's meant to have,
e.g. a euclidean structure (orthogonality).

What has instead a meaning in that plane is the area enclosed by a
closed curve (the integral $\oint\!p\,dq$). Maybe you don't think of an
area without a euclidean structure, but this is actually possible.
And that area is interesting because it's invariant under canonical
transformations. I assume you'll see that going on with Hamiltonian
mechanics.