# Demonstration of the existence of a scalar potential for a conservatice force

Tags: forces, work, potential, potential-energy, conservative-field

Mathematically a vector field, $\vec{F}$, is conservative if:

$$\oint_{\gamma} (\vec{F}.d\vec{l})=0$$

Physically, the integral is the same as the work done by a force $\vec{F}$ on a body in a closed path. I intend to demonstrate mathematically that a conservative force assumes a scalar potential, i.e:

$$\oint_{\gamma} (\vec{F}.d\vec{l})=0 \Leftrightarrow \vec{F}=-\vec{\nabla} U$$

where $U$ is the scalar potential.

I know that $$\vec{F}=-\vec{\nabla} U \Rightarrow\oint_{\gamma} (\vec{F}.d\vec{l})=0  $$

(Using Stokes theorem: $\oint_{\gamma} (\vec{F}.d\vec{l})=\int_S \left([\vec{\nabla} \times\vec{F}].\vec{n}\right) dS$. Using Schwarz lemma, we have that $ [\vec{\nabla} \times\vec{\nabla}U]=0. $ So, $\oint_{\gamma} (\vec{F}.d\vec{l})=0.$)

My problem is that I can't demonstrate the inverse, i.e:

$$\oint_{\gamma} (\vec{F}.d\vec{l})=0\Rightarrow\vec{F}=  -\vec{\nabla} U $$

I got a more general solution that is different of $\vec{F}=  -\vec{\nabla} U. $

How could I do this?

Comment: might be useful: [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition)

Comment: Each connected regions should be simply connected in order to demonstrate that a circulation-free vector field is a gradient field.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173469/2451

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll first show you how to show that $\oint_\gamma F = 0$ implies $F = -\mathrm{d} U$ and then we'll discuss that *mathematically* the problem lies *in the other direction*.

1. If we know that $\oint_\gamma F = 0$ then we can define the potential $U$ by fixing a point $x_0$ and then setting
   $$ U(x) := \int_\gamma F$$
   for *any* path between $x_0$ and $x$. This is well-defined since for any other path $\gamma'$ from $x_0$ to $x$ we have that we can form a loop $\ell$ by going first along $\gamma$ and then along $\gamma'$ in the reverse direction so that
   $$ \int_\gamma F - \int_{\gamma'} F = \oint_\ell F = 0$$
   so the potential is well-defined. It's not hard to check that the gradient of $U$ is $F$.
2. The converse direction has a subtlety: You have assumed that there is a surface $S$ such that its boundary is $\partial S = \gamma$ for every path $\gamma$. This is only true in [simply-connected spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space), but not in general. However, that being a gradient implies all loop integrals being zero *is* true in all spaces, we simply need to apply Stokes' theorem in its most basic form, the fundamental theorem of calculus. It says that for $\gamma$ starting at $x_1$ and ending at $x_2$, we have
   $$ \int_\gamma \mathrm{d}U = \int_{\partial \gamma} U = U(x_2)-U(x_1)$$
   and for loops $x_1=x_2$, so $\oint_\ell F = \oint_\ell \mathrm{d}U = 0$.

Now, it's actually important to realize that in non-simply connected spaces, there are *curl-free vector fields* which are not the gradient of a scalar function. For instance, on $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$ we have
$$ V(x,y) = \frac{x}{r}\partial_x + \frac{y}{r}\partial_y$$
with $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ as a curl-free vector field that is not a gradient, and also has a non-zero loop integral: Integrating it along anyloop that goes around the origin once, you get $2\pi$.

This is also of importance physically, for instance, it is the observation underlying the [Aharonov-Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect). While the magnetic field is zero everywhere outside the solenoid, the magnetic vector potential is not *globally* the gradient of a single scalar potential although its curl vanishes, and consequently its integral around a loop around the solenoid is non-zero.