# Curl of Magnetic Field in Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, vector-fields

I'm struggling to understand why the curl of this magnetic vector field would be zero:

$$B(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2)},\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)},0\right)$$

This cartesian field was derived from the equation for a long, straight current carrying wire, with current flowing on the Z axis. I found this derivation [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/magnetic-field-equation-in-spherical-coordinates-to-cartesian-coordinates.572930/).
Note that I removed the constants for simplicity ($\frac{\mu_0*I}{2\pi}$)

If I plot this field (shown in x-y Plane), it looks obvious that it should have curl; since the magnitude of the field lines increase approaching the center, any point in this graph should "spin" clockwise. I realize that this is an intuitive definition of curl, so please correct me if I'm wrong for using it.
[image]

Also, since this equation was derived from a magnetic field equation, barring any computation error, this HAS TO have curl from Ampere's/Maxwell's Law:
$$\nabla X B=\frac{1}{c}\left(4\pi J + \frac{dE}{dt}\right)$$
In the constant current example, $\frac{dE}{dt}=0$, but current density $J$ is proportional to current and distance from the wire.

However, when I calculate the curl of this it results with zero:

$$[-2*\frac{x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} - 2*\frac{y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} + \frac{2}{(x^2 + y^2)}]\hat k=0$$

If anyone could help out mistakes or poor assumptions made here, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The current density is *not* proportional to the distance from the wire - the current density which yields that magnetic field is zero everywhere except the origin, where it is a delta function.

Comment: @J. Murray: I see your point about the current density -- I believe I made the mistake of using average current. To clarify though, the B field (flux density) wouldn't be zero outside the wire? You can directly measure the field/flux about a current flow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this vector field curl-free?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302811/why-is-this-vector-field-curl-free)  See, in particular, Diracology's answer (currently the second on the page.)

Comment: Also, welcome to [Physics.SE]!  If this question does get closed as a duplicate, please don't take it personally;  it has happened to all of us.  This is a well-thought-out question, and I encourage you to stick around and ask more such questions.

Comment: Your calculation of the curl gives $0/0$, not $0$, when $x$ and $y$ are $0$.