# Why are systems in classical mechanics sets and not vector spaces?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, vectors, topology

One of my professors told me that a state in a classical system is an element of a set, while in quantum it's an element of a vector space.
From that, we combine systems in classical physics using a Cartesian product, while in quantum using a tensor product.

I'm confused, don't we describe everything in classical mechanics having a position and a velocity, which is a vector, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often the [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)) (of generalized positions) in classical mechanics is taken to be a [differential manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold) $M$ (which is not necessarily an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space)). The generalized velocities are then tangent vectors in the [tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle) $TM$. In other words: Generalized velocities are vectors, but generalized positions need not be.

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296519/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80775/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the difference might not be that sharp. the Koopman-von Neumann formalism describe classical (hamiltonian) mechanics as vectors in a Hilbert Space, and quantum mechanics can be described as a dynamics in a symplectic/phase space.